# why is the error in this program c++?

Tags: c++

I don't understand this program, I don't get why number is initialized to 1 when the program takes user input.
This is how I understand the program which is obviously wrong:

You enter the factorial number, lets says I enter 6, it goes to the while loop because 6 is greater than 1.
Now `factorial` is 1, and `number` is 6, `6 * 1 = 6`. Then `6 - 1 = 5`, so `factorial` is 5 but i get 720 as output.

i don't think I understand the while loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // declaration of the variables
    int factorial, number;

    // initialization of the variables
    factorial = 1;
    number = 1;

    // Prompt the user to enter the upper limit of integers
    cout << "Please enter the number of the factorial";
    cin >> number;

    // using the while loop find out the factorial
    while (number > 1)
    {
        factorial = factorial * number;
        number = number - 1;
    }
    cout << "The factorial is " << factorial;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program works correctly.

```
6! = 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 = 720.
```

Btw, use recursion for such recursive problems.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //declaration of the variabe
    unsigned int number;

    //prompt the user to enter the upper limit of integers
    cout << "Please enter the number of the factorial";
    cin >> number;

    cout << factorial(number);

    return 0;
}

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use a look-up table, which allows for O(1) complexity (as opposed to O(n) complexity). Here is an example of a look-up table implementation: https://gist.github.com/1578501.

Comment: Look-up tables does not solve the problem if the input domain is infinite :) But yes, I know how to use a look-up table and it's better when you already know the input domain.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a "<" in last line of the program. It should be

```
cout<<"The factorial is "<<factorial;
```

After making this change when I compile and run the program it works for me correctly i.e computes the correct factorial. For example factorial of 5 i.e 5!=5*4*3*2*1=120

Answer (score 1):

The initial assignment of `number` is indeed unnecessary. However, you should check the input operation for errors:

```
int factorial = 1;
int number;

if (!(std::cin >> number))
{
    /* error! */
    return 1; // i.e. abort the program
}

while (number > 1) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is initialised to 1 because of the following condition:

```
Factorial(0) = 1
Factorial(1) = 1
```

So if  a user inputs a number less than **2**, you do not need some calculations, you just output **1**

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that there is an error in your code:

```
cout<<"The factorial is " < factorial;
```

should be:

```
cout<<"The factorial is " << factorial;
```

Correcting this should fix a compile error.

**The essence of this code is:**

1. Get a number (`int number`) from user
2. Print print the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of `number`